# DocumentDB DeleteDocumentAsync() without partition key

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Per [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-documentdb-dotnet), you must spec the partition key when calling the delete.

So, if you created a collection without a partition key, does that mean you cannot delete any docs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The requirement is only for partitioned collections.

If you're just using a single-partition (10GB) collection, just call `DeleteDocumentAsync()` without the `RequestOptions` property (as it will default to null), or leave off `PartitionKey` from `RequestOptions` if you're setting other options, since `RequestOptions` is used for specifying the partition key.

The documentation for `DeleteDocumentAsync()` is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.deletedocumentasync.aspx).

Comment: David, please explain if this is a doc problem or a reader problem.  Seems the doc doesn't make the suggestion that you posted here. Or was I reading the wrong doc?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but... the documentation you were pointing at was more of a walkthrough/tutorial. Take a look at the actual docs for `DeleteDocumentAsync()` - you'll see that `RequestOptions` is optional. But docs aside, think about it logically - why would you specify a partition key if you didn't have one?

Comment: I raised this question because the doc that I was reading stated that 
"Delete a document. The partition key is required"
Which didn't make sense.  This is why my question was somewhat sarcastic..  And in my follow up question I was asking you (you being an SME), if the flaw was on my end or the doc.  The doc doesn't suggest that you need a partition key only if you are partitioning,,Now do you see where I am coming from?

Comment: The doc needs to be corrected so it is clear that if you are not partitioning, you do not need the key.  It densest matter if there are are other docs that explain this.  This doc isn't Titled "Azure CosmosDB: Develop with the DocumentDB API in .NET with partitions".  Nor does it refer to deletion in case where there are no partitions

Comment: That doc is on [github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-documentdb-dotnet.md), and this is a great opportunity for you to contribute to it, mentioning pk being not needed for 10gb collections, & submit a PR. But keep in mind: at the top of the doc, the tutorial explicitly calls out the fact that it'll be walking through creating a collection w/partition key, querying w/partition key (including fan-out when no partition key specified), and deleting w/partition key. Throughout the entire writeup, partition key is mentioned.